# How to update IList property using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a model which has a property which is IList.

```
public class SomeClass
{
 public IList<CustomClass> CustomProperty1
}
```

using reflection i need to add the values to the above property. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need to use reflection?  Wouldn't it be easier to just do it with normal code?

Comment: It is the current code implementation there is a KeyValuePair with the class instance which has the properties to be updated.

Comment: Joel's right - you can't do this. The question, as it stands, is of little value to the community. Perhaps you could show us your real code and we could help you with other options?

Comment: IEnumerable could be implemented a ton of ways. There doesnt even have to be a backing field. Without the source code or a disassembly you wont know if its possible.

Comment: @TusharJ - Please don't ask a "simplified" question - if this is about updating a `KeyValuePair<K, V>` then ask specifically about that.

Comment: @TusharJ - Now your question is getting a bit ridiculous. You don't need reflection if the return type is an `IList<CustomClass>`. Just use `.Add(...)`. Can you please ask the real question based on your real code?

Answer (score 1):

You can't through IEnuerable. It'd have to be IList or some other interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.Concat()` linq method to do it.

```
SomeClass c = /* ... */
CustomClass[] extraItems = new CustomClass[] { /* ... */ };
c.CustomProperty1 = c.CustomProperty1.Concat(extraItems);
```

This doesn't add more items to the enumerable, but rather assigns a *new* enumerable that has more items in it.

This doesn't use reflection, but I'm assuming you don't really *have* to use reflection.

Comment: This is technically correct, but the OP really has "dumbed-down" his question so much that I suspect that what he has asked isn't actually what he's trying to do.